# Simple Linux pipe program, data is not received

Tags: c, linux, ipc, pipe, communication

I have a simple Linux C program that I'm writing to help me better understand IPC, right now I'm trying to build it with pipes.
 I have a single code base that I run in two different terminal windows as two different executables (so they can talk to each other). However I'm not doing something correct, because I never get any data to read, but I'm not sure what...

**NOTE** This is not the full code, I chopped out the output/input/validation to save space. But it's noted in the comments in the program below.

```
void main()
{
  int pipefd[2], n;
  char input = 0;
  char buffer[100] = {0};
  char outpipe[100] = {0};

  if(pipe(pipefd) < 0) {
    printf("FAILED TO MAKE PIPES\n");
    return;
  }

  printf("Starting up, read fd = %d, write fd = %d\n", pipefd[0],pipefd[1]);

  do {
    //print menu options (send message, get message, get my fd, 
    // set a fd to talk to, quit)

    // if "send a message":
    {
      printf("What would you like to send?\n");
      fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
      write(pipefd[1], buffer, strlen(buffer));
    }
    //else if "read a message":
    {
      if(open(outpipe, 0) < 0)
          printf("Couldn't open the pipe!\n");
      else {
        n = read(outpipe, buffer, 100);
        printf("I got a read of %d bytes\nIt was %s\n",n, buffer);
        close(outpipe);
      }
    }
    //else if "get my file descriptor":
      printf("My fd tag is: /proc/%d/fd/%d\n", (int)getpid(), pipefd[0]);
    //else if "set a file descriptor to talk to":
    {
      printf("What is the pipe's file descriptor?\n");
      fgets(outpipe, 100, stdin);
      n = strlen(outpipe) - 1;
      outpipe[n] = '\0';
    }
  } while (input != 'Q');
return;
}
```

I know the pipes are created successfully, I verified the file descriptors are in place:

```
lr-x------ 1 mike users 64 Sep 26 23:31 3 -> pipe:[33443]
l-wx------ 1 mike users 64 Sep 26 23:31 4 -> pipe:[33443]
```

Looks like the permissions are OK (read on pipe 3, write on pipe 4).

I use it as such:

```
//terminal 1
Pick an option:
3
My fd tag is: /proc/8956/fd/3

//terminal 2
Pick an option:
4
What is the pipe's file descriptor?
/proc/8956/fd/3

Pick an option:
1
What would you like to send?
hello

//terminal 1
Pick an option:
2
I got a read of -1 bytes
It was
```

Is there anything obviously wrong that I'm doing here? My reads always get "-1" return value...

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at Beej's guide: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/

Comment: I'm surprised your program even compiles, as calls like the one to `read` and `close` for the file is wrong.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Yup, compiles nicely, no warnings either. I guess it's close enough for gcc. What about the calls are incorrect?

Comment: @Mat - I printed it, and it's correct. The `strlen()-1` set to '\0' is to get rid of the `'\n'` that's appended by fgets

Comment: A couple of other things, you never change `input` so it will loop forever; And you never say _where_ you get the `-1` return value; Lastly you don't print the error in case of error. Use e.g. [`perror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror) to print a readable message.

Comment: @Mike: sorry, forgot about that. Turn on your compiler warnings though.

Comment: The variable `outpipe` is an array oc `char`, the `read` and `close` functions expect a file descriptor (i.e. and `int`). Read the manual pages.

Comment: These are the warnings I get when I compile: ./ipctest.c: In function ‘main’:
./ipctest.c:32:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘read’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/unistd.h:361:16: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
./ipctest.c:34:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘close’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/unistd.h:354:12: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
./ipctest.c:43:11: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’ [enabled by default]

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - OK, first input/errors are checked (note the edit to the post) it's in the comments. Second the "-1" is number of bytes I get back (check the usage part I posted). However your last point is totally accurate. Is what I'm doing not possible? How can I get the fd as an `int` value to my other executable. I found the fd's in `/proc/<pid>/fd/` but that's internal to that binary isn't it?

Comment: @L0j1k - `atoi()` of what? `atoi("/proc/<pid>/fd/3")`... I can't think that's going to work. `atoi("3")` shouldn't either since every application I make has its own 1, 2, 3, 4 file descriptors...

Comment: Take a look at http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/index.html and he will provide you with enlightenment. Beej is the man! :)

Comment: You already have the pipe file descriptors... You don't need to open anything. Just use the descriptors given by the `pipe` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have misunderstood how pipe works. A pipe is an anonymous file descriptor that is not going by file in the file system. The files in `/proc/<pid>/fd` you don't have to care about.

Here is a rewrite of what you are trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pipefds[2];
    char input[128];
    char output[128];
    ssize_t nread;

    if (pipe(pipefds) == -1)
    {
        perror("Could not create pipe");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Enter input: ");
    if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not read input");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* "Remove" newline from input */
    if (input[strlen(input) - 1] == '\n')
        input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';

    /* Now write the received input to the pipe */
    if (write(pipefds[1], input, strlen(input) + 1) == -1)
    {
        perror("Could not write to pipe");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Now read from the pipe */
    if ((nread = read(pipefds[0], output, sizeof(output))) == -1)
    {
        perror("Could not reaf from pipe");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* We don't need to terminate as we send with the '\0' */

    printf("Received: \"%s\"\n", output);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You are correct-ish. I was indeed confused about what I was trying to do because I missunderstood pipes. But I'm not trying to get a program to talk to itself, or to a child process. I guess what I really wanted was a named pipe, or FIFO, for them to talk to each other

Comment: @Mike Then I suggest you look at [`mkfifo(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) or [`mkfifo(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkfifo).

Comment: Was not even aware of `mkfifo()`, that's a great tool. The book I was looking at (and L0j1k's link) uses `mknod()`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is your primary concern:

```
./ipctest.c: In function ‘main’:

./ipctest.c:32:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘read’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/unistd.h:361:16: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’

./ipctest.c:34:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘close’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/unistd.h:354:12: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
```

Look at the data types required for a certain function... :)

Comment: Yup, as Joachim Pileborg, pointed out, wrong arguments.. that was dumb on my part. What options are you running gcc with? I'm not getting any warnings.

Comment: `mike@linux-4puc:~> gcc -Werror pipe_tester.c`
`mike@linux-4puc:~> ` wow... still nothing. (gcc version 4.6.2 SUSE Linux).

Comment: Interesting! try `gcc -Wall pipe_tester.c`

Comment: Bingo. Adding `-Wall` tells me `implicit declaration of getpid()` `read()` and others. Added `#include <unistd.h>` and now I'm getting the argument warning. Interesting it compiled with just `stdio.h` and `string.h`